# SQL Pivot Rows to Column

Tags: sql, pivot, rows, large-data

Thought this would be easy but I am having trouble. I need to pivot (or unpivot) a table (called da_LMP_downloads) with 100,000+ rows. I'm starting with this: [table_before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o1aT.jpg)

Before:

Market Day | Node| Node_Type | LMP_Value| HE1 | HE2| HE 3|.......|HE24|

10/1/12 |AEC| Interface | LMP | 17.82 | 16.44 | 16.45

10/1/12 |AEC| Interface | MCC | .14 | .16 | .62

10/1/12 |AEC| Interface | MLC | -.38 | -.34 | .34

But need it to look like this after the pivot: [table_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh7cq.jpg)

After:

Market_Day | Node | HE | daLMP | daMCC | daMLC

10/1/12 | AEC | 1 | 17.82 | .14 | -.38

10/1/12 | AEC | 2| 16.44| .16 | -.34

10/1/12 | AEC | 3 | 16.45 | .62 | .34

Comment: What is your RDBMs ?

Comment: This is an UNPIVOT (columns into rows) if the image AFTER is correct (6 columns) & it is essential we know the dbms because the syntax differs by dbms vendor

Comment: Please add some sample data into your question (NOT an image, just text) or setup a sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Is this for within Excel? Why don't you use Pivot Tables?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I use SQL Server. @waqasahmed Pivot tables don't work as well for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your dbms is SQL Server then you can use CROSS APPLY with VALUES to achieve the "unpivot" portion, but you also need a small "pivot" operation as well it appears and for that a GROUP BY will work. Note this is ONLY applicable to SQL Server, other databases have very different syntax for unpivot/pivot.

```
/* input looks like this...
Market_Day Node Node_Type LMP_Value HE1   HE2   .... HE24
2012-10-01 AEC Interface  LMP       17.82 16.44 .... 19.77
*/
SELECT
      sq.Market_Day
    , sq.Node
    , sq.Node_Type
    , sq.HE
    , MAX(sq.daLMP) AS daLMP
    , MAX(sq.daMCC) AS daMCC
    , MAX(sq.daMLC) AS daMLC
FROM (
      SELECT
            t.Market_Day
          , t.Node
          , t.Node_Type
          , ca.HE
          , CASE WHEN LMP_Value = 'LMP' THEN ca.val END AS daLMP
          , CASE WHEN LMP_Value = 'MCC' THEN ca.val END AS daMCC
          , CASE WHEN LMP_Value = 'MLC' THEN ca.val END AS daMLC
      FROM Table1 t
            CROSS APPLY (
                  VALUES
                        (1, HE1)
                      , (2, HE2)
                      , (3, HE3)
                      , (4, HE4)
                      , (5, HE5)
                      , (6, HE6)
                      , (7, HE7)
                      , (8, HE8)
                      , (9, HE9)
                      , (10, HE10)
                      , (11, HE11)
                      , (12, HE12)
                      , (13, HE13)
                      , (14, HE14)
                      , (15, HE15)
                      , (16, HE16)
                      , (17, HE17)
                      , (18, HE18)
                      , (19, HE19)
                      , (20, HE20)
                      , (21, HE21)
                      , (22, HE22)
                      , (23, HE23)
                      , (24, HE24)
                        ) AS ca (HE, val)
    ) AS sq
GROUP BY
      sq.Market_Day
    , sq.Node
    , sq.Node_Type
    , sq.HE
```

Note TSQL actually does have both "pivot" and "unpivot" operators but I find using cross apply/values to be as efficient and simpler to implement.

Comment: thanks I will try this code out tomorrow. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think I'm probably doing something wrong. I'm getting some errors such as The multi-part identifier "t.Market_Day" could not be bound. In your code I think I substitute Table1 for the name of my table, DA_LMP_DOWNLOADS ? Did I miss something? Thanks for your help @Used_By_Already

Comment: No, it was my fault. in TSQL each subquery **MUST** have an alias, I had given the subquery containing the cross apply etc the alias of "sq" so in the top select clause, and the final group by clause, the columns should be referenced by that alias. sorry, I have corrected it now. You can choose a different alias I used "sq" to indicate subquery

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Table1 should be my current table correct? I will try this out tonight. Many thanks.

Comment: yes put in your real table name instead of "table1" but leave the alias t  and it should work

Comment: Thanks a million, worked perfectly. Appreciate the help.